# Bounds on moments of sample mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

> Let $X_i$s be i.i.d zero mean random variables whose $p$-th moments are finite. Prove
>   $$E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right)^p\right]\leq C_p n^{p/2}$$
>   where $C_p$ is a constant independent of $n$.

My effort: I think we have to expand the sum and then say each term is of $k$-th moment, count the number of them and the upper bound. This seems to be messy. Is there a better solution? Or, is it a name of a theorem?

Comment: Answer for $p \leq 2$: for $p=2$ this is trivial. If $p<2$ let $Y=(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i)^{2}$. Then $EY^{p/2} \leq (EY)^{p/2}=(nEX_1^{2})^{p/2}=C_pn^{p/2}$ where $C_p= (EX_1^{2})^{p/2}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks. Can you tell me how it is any easy consequence of clt?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't complete that argument.

Comment: The inequality follows by an easy calculation if $p$ is an even integer. All you have to do is to expand $(\sum X_i)^{p}$. The highest power you get in the coefficients is $n^{k}$ where $p=2k$. I don't know if these special cases are of any help in proving the result for  arbitrary $p$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks. Yes, i need p integer. The way you said is what i thought about and stated above.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy if i find a theorem or proof for general $p$ that would be great

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Once you have it for even integers, you can find a way to use the Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem. There is probably an easier method using truncation and [log convexity of p-norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem#Motivation). One might also succeed using a [tensorization trick](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/tricks-wiki-article-the-tensor-product-trick/). Also, the statement is false for $p<2$ (notice that in your proof you are assuming that $E[X_1^2]$ is finite, which is not given to us).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that $p\geq 2$.

By [Marcinkiewicz–Zygmund inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcinkiewicz%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality), there exists $B_p$ such that $$E\left(  \left\vert \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right\vert ^{p}\right)\leq B_{p}E\left(  \left(  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\vert X_{i}\right\vert ^{2}\right)  _{{}}^{p/2}\right)=B_pn^{p/2}E\left(  \left( \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\vert X_{i}\right\vert ^{2}\right)  _{{}}^{p/2}\right)$$

Since $x\mapsto x^{p/2}$ is convex, $$\left(\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\vert X_{i}\right\vert ^{2}\right)  _{{}}^{p/2}\leq \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|^p $$
hence

$$E\left(  \left\vert \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right\vert ^{p}\right)\leq 
B_pn^{p/2}E\left( \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|^p  \right) = B_pn^{p/2} E(|X_1|^p)
$$

Comment: Thanks for catching this, I had read it in the comments and did not bother checking.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see around it is to use [Khintchine inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khintchine_inequality). 
The key point is that if $F$ is a convex function, and $X_i$ and $X'_i$ two i.i.d. zero mean random variables:
$$
E\left[F(X_i)\right]=E\left[F\bigg(X_i-E(X'_i)\bigg)\right]\leq E\left[F\bigg(X_i-X'_i\bigg)\right]
$$
This is a symmetrization argument since $X_i-X'_i$ is now symmetric and has the same distribution as $\epsilon_iX_i$ where $\epsilon_i$ has the Rademacher's distribution. This particularly means that for $p\geq 1$:
$$
E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^p\right]\leq E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_iX_i\right)^p\right].
$$
Note that if $p$ is not an integer and the moments are to be well defined, the absolute values should be considered.

Using Khintchine inequality, there is a constant $A_p$ such that:
$$
E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i X_i\right)^p\right]\leq A_p E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |\epsilon_i X_i|^2\right)^{p/2}\right].
$$
Note that $|\epsilon_i|^2=1$. The last step is to use Holder's inequality to show that:
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (|X_i|^2)^{p/2}\right)^{2/p}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1^q\right)^{1/q}
$$
where $\frac 2p+\frac 1q=1$. Combining this with the previous inequality, we get:
$$
E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|^2\right)^{p/2}\right]\leq E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|^p\right)\right]n^{p/2q}.
$$
Using $\frac{p}{2q}=\frac p2-1$, the inequality follows with the constant $C_p=A_p E(|X|^p)$. Note that to use Holder's inequality, $p$ should be bigger than  or equal to $2$.

Comment: I believe the proof only works for $\frac p2 -1 \geq 0$, i.e., $p\ge 2$. In fact the statement is false for $p \in [1,2]$.

Comment: You are right; this is required for Holder's inequality step. Although it still holds for $p=2$; and for $p=1$ the inequality holds trivially.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is correct as stated for $p \in \Bbb N$. However, if $p$ is non-integer then there should be absolute-value signs within the expectation (i.e., $|\sum X_i|^p$) or else the random variable is not well-defined. Assuming this, I would just like to remark that the statement is false for $p \in (0,2)$.

An easy counterexample is given as follows: Let $X_i$ be $\alpha$-stable random variables for some $\alpha \in (0,2)$, i.e., they are characterized by the fact that $\Bbb E[e^{itX_1}] = e^{-|t|^{\alpha}}$.

It is checked easily enough that $$a_1X_1+...+a_nX_n \stackrel{d}{=} (|a_1|^{\alpha}+...+|a_n|^{\alpha})^{1/\alpha} X_1.$$

Now, it is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) that $X_i$ have finite mean as long as $\alpha>1$. Thus if we set $a_i=1$ in the above distributional equality, we get: $$\Bbb E \bigg| \sum_1^n X_i \bigg| = n^{1/\alpha} \Bbb E|X_1|,$$ which gives a counterexample for $p=1$. One may use the same random variables (and a similar argument) to get counterexamples for every $p \in (0,2)$.

Comment: I  think the interval should be open $(1,2)$.

Comment: @Arash Half-open, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: But for $p=1$ the expectation is zero anyway so the inequality is true.

Comment: I see, there should be an absolute value there otherwise the thing is not even well-defined for non-integer $p$. Technically speaking you are right though; I will edit.

Comment: That's exactly the point; for non-integer $p$,  I assume that the original problem means the absolute moment of course.

Comment: Well I edited it. Hopefully it's good now.

Comment: It is very good idea to add absolute value there to make it well defined. Although the question in the original problem is still valid for integer $p$ and indeed correct for all $p\in\mathbb N$.