# Moments of sample mean

Tags: probability, monte-carlo

I am trying to understand the answer to questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901196/bounds-on-moments-of-sample-mean) and square it with what I know to be true. In particular, the result there is that for a centered random variable $X$

$$
E\left[\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^p\right]  \leq C_p E[|X|^p]
$$

for some constant $C_p$. I know that this bound is sharp (by, for example, the Marcinkiewicz–Zygmund inequality). However, this means that if $X$ does not have a finite $p$ moment, the $p$ moment of the sample mean is infinite. But then, I know that

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
$$

converges to a standard normal random variable as $n \to \infty$ by the Central Limit Theorem which should have finite moments for any $p$. In fact for $n$ large enough, the previous average is approximately normal.
How do I square these two facts? Are the $p$ moments of a sample mean finite or not in this case?

Comment: Convergence in distribution does not in general imply convergence of the $p$-moments. It is possible to have that the $p$-moments of the sequence are infinite for all $n$, but have a finite $p$-moment in the limit.

Comment: Ah of course. I knew I was missing something obvious.